# font set problems in beamer

Tags: beamer, fontspec

i want to set the main font in my beamer as "Consolas" i do like this :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Consolas}
\begin{frame}
we discuss the ambiguities of existing security definitions and then provide a general framework for defining AKE security when involve strong adversary capabilities
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but after compile it , the font doesn't change, it is the same with that before the main font was set. what's the reason?

Comment: Please consider expanding your posting by posting a Minimum Working Example (MWE) of what you've done so far. "Nothing happens" is a rather broad term -- does the document fail to compile, or is a font other than Consolas in use? Please also indicate which TeX format you use.

Comment: What does "nothing" mean in this context? Do you at least get warnings or error messages in the log file (*.log)? Furthermore it could be very helpful if you add an example that is as short as possible, demonstrates the problem and is compilable as is.

Answer (score 17):

At the moment you only set the main font of the document. You need to specify the sans serif font family because that's what the »[beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)« classes uses in the end.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\setmainfont{Consolas}
\setsansfont{Consolas}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
we discuss the ambiguities of existing security definitions and then provide a general framework for defining AKE security when involve strong adversary capabilities
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Do you really want to use a mono spaced font for your presentation?

Comment: One of the most frustrating things about latex is that sometimes the answer to "How would one do X?" is "Latex does not find X aesthetically pleasing. You shouldn't do X." But yeah, a presentation in monospaced font may be too creative.

Answer (score 8):

By default `beamer` uses a sans-serif font.  You can set that directly, by `\setsansfont` instead of `\setmainfont`, or you can stay with `\setmainfont` and use the `serif` font theme of `beamer`.  Here is the latter:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Consolas}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  We discuss the ambiguities of existing security definitions and then
  provide a general framework for defining AKE security when involve
  strong adversary capabilities.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```