# beamer does not honour \setmainfont, how to fix?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I have a local set of `.ttf` files which I'd like to use in my presentation.

When I create an article document the font gets selected properly:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont [ Path = fonts/open-sans/, 
        Extension      = .ttf,
        UprightFont = *-Regular,
        BoldFont = *-Semibold,
        BoldItalicFont = *-SemiboldItalic,
        ItalicFont = *-Italic
    ] {OpenSans}

    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \begin{document}
            1234567890 
            \blindtext
    \end{document}
```

But when I change this to a `beamer` presentation I end up with a different font:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont [ Path = fonts/open-sans/, 
        Extension      = .ttf,
        UprightFont = *-Regular,
        BoldFont = *-Semibold,
        BoldItalicFont = *-SemiboldItalic,
        ItalicFont = *-Italic
    ] {OpenSans}

    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
            1234567890 
            \blindtext
        \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Here you see the difference:

[image]

The lower text is the right font in `article` mode, the upper one the `beamer` standard.

I even tried to use `\setbeamerfont` but this didn't change anything.

Can somebody please point me how to convince the `beamer` class to use the provided font files?

This is my environment:

```
$ lualatex --version
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (rev 5238)

$lualatex testfonds-article.tex | grep "Document Class: beamer"
Document Class: beamer 2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations (rc
```

Comment: Maybe try with `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` after the documentclass. Can't test myself, as I don't have this font.

Comment: '\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}' does not make a difference. :o(

Comment: And this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134822/36296

Comment: Or this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79423/36296

Comment: and this tex.stackexchange.com/a/34966/36296

Comment: this is the solution: <tex.stackexchange.com/a/134822/36296> , thanks!