# Atom will not compile when using fontspec package

Tags: fontspec, atom

I'm trying to compile a Beamer document using the `fontspec` package, but it complains with the following error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty:43:
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [ }]
```

I have found the discussion at this page which suggests it should work fine:
[font set problems in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134816/font-set-problems-in-beamer#134822)

I have tried creating an MWE using the code on the answers, such as this (minimised from the original answer):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setsansfont{Consolas}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
frame text goes here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong that Beamer can't load `fontspec`?

Error from the log file:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

Interestingly, I think this has something to do with Atom and the latex package, as TexShop doesn't seem to throw up the same error.

UPDATE:
Having checked the .log, at @samcarter's suggestion, it appeared the engine was still typesetting with pdflatex.

After some hunting around, this turned out to be an issue with Atom or, at least, Atom's settings.
I have two LaTeX packages installed: `latextools` and `latex`.

Comment: Are you using LuaLaTeX to compile the document? I don't experience any problems when compiling your code on a TeXLive2016 system with LuaLaTeX as the format. Any chance you could update your TeXLive distribution from 2015 to 2016?

Comment: Hmm, good point. I'd overlooked that. dl-ing now and will report back.

Comment: also you need to show the actual error message, that will be a multiple line section of the log file from `!` to `?`  show in a code section, so line breaks are preserved.

Comment: But before you update, answer the first question (are you using LuaLaTex (or XeLaTeX)?) The Error message suggests you are not.

Comment: @pschulz: yes, I'm using xelatex. In Atom > Preferences > Packages > latex I have selected Engine to be xelatex.

Comment: Ok, thats good. I also can confirm the document working with a current release of XeLaTeX and luaLaTeX. I don't know anything about Atom, sorry.

Comment: Can you please add the beginning of the log file? This will show if the tex engine you selected is in fact the one used.

Answer (score 3):

If you're having this problem then the solution can be found in Atom's settings pane.

I have two LaTeX packages installed so I can only comment for these, not others: `latextools` and `latex`.

On OS X/macOS:

```
Atom > Preferences > Packages > latex > Settings
```

ensure that the Engine is `xelatex`, and also that:

```
Atom > Preferences > Packages > latextools > Settings > Builder Settings > Builder Settings Program
```

is set to `xelatex`

It may be necessary to flush (delete) logs etc. to enable a clean typeset.