# Unicode glyph not displaying in LuaTeX

Tags: beamer, luatex, unicode

I need to use some unicode glyphs relating to greek metric, namely ⎯ ⏑  ⏒   ⏓   ⏔   ⏕   ⏖, but I can't make them display on the document.

I've got

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Symbola}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{description}
            \item[test] ⎯⏔⎯⏔⎯⏔⎯⏔⎯⏔⎯
            \item 
        \end{description}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But on the pdf it's missing

Comment: Since `beamer` defaults to sans serif, you need `\setsansfont{Symbola}`. And you shouldn’t use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with `fontspec`.

Comment: Thank you! it works now.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134816