# A Hebrew title doesn't print in a beamer presentation that uses babel

Tags: beamer, titles, babel, hebrew

This question was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134816/21685). But are they duplicates?

When a future user will encounter a situation as described in my post, in which a Hebrew title doesn't show in a beamer presentation, will they consider searching for a question in which the text of an English presentation appears, but is resilient to font changes via the `\setmainfont` command? All the more so considering that the Hebrew presentation doesn't use the `\setmainfont` command explicitly.

Conversely, will a future user who will encounter a situation as described in the other post, in which changing beamer's font via `\setmainfont` leaves the font intact, try looking up my question about Hebrew titles not showing up in `beamer`+`babel`?

These questions are as much duplicates of each other as are two medical cases of two different patients exhibiting different symptoms when the symptoms are eventually determined to have resulted from the same underlying disease.

---

The following LaTeX document was saved at `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{hebrew}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSans}

\title{כותרת}
\date{2022}
\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

The code was meant to create a simple presentation with a single slide: a title slide, containing the title `כותרת` in Hebrew. The code uses the `babel` package as the language manager.

Then the following commands were executed in the Terminal:

> > cd ~
> > lualatex test

The compilation completed successfully, with barely a warning (the single warning was: `Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File 'test.out' has changed.`), and the file `~/test.pdf` was created. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows.

[image: Beamer file with Hebrew]

Why is the title missing? How can it be fixed?

Comment: beamer use sans serif, so you need `\babelfont{sf}{FreeSans}`.

Comment: Regarding the duplicate closure: the idea of duplicates is that they are signposts, that is why they are not deleted or made less visible. If a new user has problems displaying a Hebrew title in beamer and search Google for "Hebrew title in Beamer" they will find _this_ question and can then click through to the other question that has the solution for their problem.